# docdokuPLM configuration

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, configuration, payara

I have installed payara 4.1, and everything needed to install docdokuPLM, 
I have configured everything as said in the wiki documentation,
but, when I try to create a user, I Have this error (sorry, it's in French)

> Erreur à la création de l'objet dont les attributs sont incorrects ou ne garantissent pas l'unicité

I have this server.log but no severe error in it
[server.log](https://pastebin.com/DCXxTB7j)

```
I think it's a configuration problem but can't handle the errors in the log file.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can find some errors in the log file. I would say, that the error more likely to be cause of your problem is the missing column from your database:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'ORGANIZATION_NAME' in 'field list' Error Code: 1054 Call:
>   INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (LOGIN, CREATIONDATE, EMAIL, LANGUAGE, NAME,
>   TIMEZONE, ORGANIZATION_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>       bind => [7 parameters bound]

Comment: I also see this, but in the form to create a new user, there is no organization name field or something like this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your backend code is not update to sync with the database.
The link between organization and account should be hold inside the ORGANIZATION_ACCOUNT table.
Just try to drop all tables and recreate them.